# function where the correlation can be controlled

Tags: covariance, correlation

Does a pair of functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ exist between some real interval $[a, b]$ where, given uniformly distributed input x~U[a, b], the Pearson correlation $\rho$ between $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ may be explicitly controlled as an input to $f_1$ and $f_2$?

To put in another way, does there exist $f_1(x, \rho_0), f_2(x, \rho_0))$ such that $\rho_0=\rho[f_1(x, \rho_0), f_2(x, \rho_0)]$, where $\rho_0 \in [0,1]$ is the input correlation and $\rho$ is the Pearson correlation function,

$\rho(f_1, f_2) = \frac{Corr(f_1[x], f_2[x])}{\sigma(f_1[x])\sigma(f_2[x])}$

where $Cov$ is the covariance function and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

The covariance function is defined as

$Cov(f_1, f_2) = \int [f_1 - \int f_1 P(x) dx][f_2 - \int f_2 P(x) dx] dx$

where $P(x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$.

It would be useful for me to have a function where the correlation over $[a, b]$ may be controlled as an input, but I can't think of one. Is it even possible to construct such a function?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ predetermined? And what's the context of this problem?

Comment: @Saad I want to test out multifidelity optimization schemes. $a$ and $b$ are not predetermined.